# How to configure jmeter for load testing a secure application if I have .pem files with me

Tags: jmeter, keystore

I am new to JMeter, just started. I have a secure application and I downloaded the .pem file. I am confused(steps converting .pem to .cer or pk12) about how to use this for accessing the application. When I tried to convert .pem to pfx it is giving error saying either private key does not match or format is different. Can anyone help with a clear list of steps to follow to use JMeter for load testing the application? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter can only work with [Java Keystores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_KeyStore) (either in JKS or PKCS12 formats) so you need to convert your .pem file into a Java Keystore.

You can do this either using [OpenSSL command-line utility](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO25984.html) like:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out keystore.p12 -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem
```

Or if you prefer you can use a GUI-based took like [Keystore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/)

Once done you can configure JMeter to use this keystore by adding the next lines to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12    
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/your/keystore.p12
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your_keystore_password_here
```

More information: [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates/)

Comment: Hi, I am not able to convert it into pkcs12 and getting following error--                               unable to load certificate
140383516595264:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE